# fgets function doesn't wait for input

Tags: c, input, fgets, scanf

I am trying to initiaze an m*n matrix line by line parsing the data with sscanf. The problem is that at the second iteration of the outer loop fgets doesn't wait for any input.

```
for(i = 0; i < m; ++i){
        if(fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp)){
            for(j = 0; j < n; ++j){
                printf("j = %d i = %d n = %d line = %s\n", j, i, n, line);//DEBUG
                if(sscanf(line+j*2, "%g", &mtx[i][j]) != 1){
                    /*Manage the error*/
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here it's the debug output:

```
j = 0 i = 0 n = 4 line = 1 7 3 0
j = 1 i = 0 n = 4 line = 1 7 3 0
j = 2 i = 0 n = 4 line = 1 7 3 0
j = 3 i = 0 n = 4 line = 1 7 3 0
j = 0 i = 1 n = 4 line =
```

And the corresponding input:

```
1 7 3 0
9 5 2 4
1 8 1 9
3 7 9 2
```

Comment: What input should it wait for? It is reading from a file.

Comment: How exactly is `line` defined?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Actually the program can read either from file or stdin.  But instead of reading the second line it pass by

Comment: Specifically, how big is `line`?  If it's not big enough to store the entire line, then `fgets` will leave input behind in `fp` (which would be read on a subsequent call).

Comment: Works OK for me: http://ideone.com/2aOvVk

Comment: @sworwitz If `line` is a pointer rather than an array, `sizeof(line)` is probably just 4 bytes, not the size of the array it points to.

Comment: @Barmar If it points to any at all....

Comment: @Barmar yes sorry I just deleted the comment. It's an array of size 256

Comment: Post more of the code. What you've written should work, since it works for me.

Comment: @Barmar: Actually you know `sizeof(line)` is at least 8 bytes since it read 4 digits, 3 spaces, and had room for NUL.

Comment: @sworwitz The input lines don't have hundreds of extraneous spaces at the end of any line, right?

Comment: No, I'll post more code

Comment: @chux there is a \n each four numbers

Comment: @sworwitz If `fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp)` read a `'\n'`, I would expect `printf("j = %d i = %d n = %d line = %s\n", j, i, n, line);` to display 2 `'\n'`, one from `line`, one from the format.  Post only shows 1.  Suggest `... line = <%s>\n"` to demarcate `line`.

Comment: @sworwitz Post the code that supports "It's an array of size 256".  Code problem is readily explained if `line `is instead an 8-byte  pointer.

Comment: You need to post enough code so that it's possible to reproduce the problem. See [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: OK I found the error.  It was quite stupid...  line is an array but I pass it to the function that contains the code above, so sizeof is actually just 8. Now I use a macro